# Can you use the same long life premium oil filter for 2 or 3 times?

Tags: engine, oil, truck, oil-life-indicator, filter

I have a 03 Mazda b3000 and bought a mobile 1 oil filter with a advertised life of 15k - 20k mi.
I figured that this filter being made of better materials, would keep my engine more protected and also allow me to use the same filter for 2 or 3 oil changes.

I know that these long life filters are usually put on newer cars with a specific engine oil system.

Perhaps the newer cars are more efficient at filtering oil and processing oil and therefore they can use the same oil longer (e.g., 7k -10k mi)?

Would the same still apply to older cars?
And Is it ok to re use a long life premium filter 2 or 3 times?

how do you know when the oil filter is no longer filtering and the drain valve on the filter is open so that the oil is just flushed back into the engine as to not starve the engine oil?